# `indextools` confilict with tikz library `external`

Tags: tikz-pgf, indexing, incompatibility, tikz-external, missing

## OS (Environment)

```
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.5
Copyright 2023 D.E. Knuth.
```

## MWE(minmal working example)

to reproduce this error, the minmal working example (`main.tex`) is as follows:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzdata/]

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{indextools}
\makeindex[title=Test Title, columns=3]

% \usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize[prefix=tikzdata/]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and a created folder `tikzdata` in the parent directory, the initial directory tree is

```
.
├── main.tex
└── tikzdata
```

after setting the environment, let's reproduce the error.

## Problem Discription

when loading `indextools` and using tikz library `external` at the same time, compile the `main.tex` using command

```shell
pdflatex --shel-escape main.tex
```

> whether i put the `tikz`-related code before or after the `indextools`

it wil through the following error message:

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex)))
Writing index file main.idx

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryexterna
l.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzexterna
lshared.code.tex))
No file main.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx)
No file main.bbl.
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -inter
action=batchmode -jobname "tikzdatamain-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main
}\input{main}"' ========

! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact
ion=batchmode -jobname "tikzdatamain-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\i
nput{main}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikzdatamain-figure0' (exp
ected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system
 calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also na
med 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Erro
r messages can be found in 'tikzdatamain-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'l
l try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.12 \end{tikzpicture}
                      
?
```

## my effort

i have seen the `indextools` document, just seeing that `indextools` is conflicting with `memoir` class, but did't refering to this error. `indextools` is a awesome package, but how can i solve the problem ? Thanks !

Comment: is the unknown class zlatex needed to demonstrate the error?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i update this problem.  previous document class `zlatex` is what i am making now. you can test the mwe on your local now. Thanks.

Comment: works fine here, be aware that the name of the option  is `--shell-escape` and not `--shel-escape`